# Need to stringify? Confusion over format of data for posting array of objects from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

I am trying to post an array of objects from jQuery/Javascript client script to server side PHP script.

Im still confused about the *format* that the object array data should be in before reaching the server.

I create an array to store the json objects

```
var jsonObjects = [];
```

I add individual json objects to the array

```
var jsonObj1 = {};
 jsonObj1.place = "London";
 jsonObj1.position = 1;

 jsonObjects.push(jsonObj1);

 var jsonObj2 = {};
 jsonObj2.place = "Melbourne";
 jsonObj2.position = 2;

 jsonObjects.push(jsonObj2);
```

..etc

I then try to post this data via ajax post (Ive tried stringifying before the post and also tried without stringifying)

e.g.

```
//var data = jsonObjects;
//var data = JSON.stringify(jsonObjects);

jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/drupal/menu_item",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data
            dataType: 'json'
             });
```

Either way on the XHR tab in Firebug it just shows a stringified version of the data 
e.g.
[{"place":"London","position":"2"}, {"place":"Melbourne","position":"2"}]

rather than it looking like what the post details have looked like before with the data broken up into parameters. Unless of course PHP finding data in the stringified state will actually work (?)

I seem to be finding conflicting details as to how sending an array of json objects to PHP should be done. At the point that the ajax request is executed what state should the data be in?
a) stringified array of objects
b) array of objects
c) something else again (?)

Any help to clarify this is much appreciated :)

Thanks,

Rowan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stringified data is just a textual representation of a JS object. Therefore, you can run `json_decode` on the stringified JS object in order to obtain PHP data structure.

On the other hand, if your objects are simple key:value ones without much depth (multi-dimensional arrays) then they can be sent as querystring and parsed into PHP's `$_POST` / `$_GET` / `$_REQUEST`

Comment: OK thanks for that. Do js objects *need* to be in a textual representation for that data to be posted to PHP?

Comment: Well, you are communicating to PHP via HTTP. So yes, whatever you send **has** to be plain-text.

Comment: Hi, yes that makes sense..I think where i got confused is I read somewhere that if you post an array of objects and specify datatype of json it will convert it to a string for you (?)

Comment: `dataType` specifies in what format you expect the response **back**. What you send to PHP is being sent over HTTP. Since HTTP cannot represent internal data structure of JavaScript, it has to convert the JS object to something that can be serialized back and forth - therefore, you have to send textual representation of the JS object - that's what stringify does. Then PHP can try to convert that piece of text via `json_decode` in its own internal data structure (array or object) which you can work with.

Comment: Ah-ha! Right..I didnt realise thats what datatype meant..and now that you point it out it makes perfect sense that to send across HTTP it has to be a string representation..thanks again!